# Compile VLC-android on Mac os

Tags: android, c++, macos, macros, vlc

```
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/doxygen.cfg
config.status: creating misc/dvdread.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
cd dvdread && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install
    CC       src/bitreader.lo
    CC       src/dvd_input.lo
    CC       src/dvd_reader.lo
    CC       src/dvd_udf.lo
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.3, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.3
libtool: and run autoconf again.
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.3, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.6.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.3
libtool: and run autoconf again.
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.3, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.6.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.3
libtool: and run autoconf again.
make[1]: *** [src/dvd_udf.lo] Error 63
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [src/dvd_reader.lo] Error 63
make[1]: *** [src/bitreader.lo] Error 63
```

I compile VLC-ANDROID on mac os, but I meet some problem; acturely, I have installed libtool2.4.6 by using brew;later, I found that mac os have install libtool2.4.3, what I installed ,libtool2.4.6, has a new name glibtool; I don't know how to deal it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, better suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks ,i have post it on the website!